# How to return char values with a template

Tags: c++, templates

I am failing to understand fully how these templates work in C++, I have a driver code that I am trying to write the header file for.  I can get this code to compile and its supposed to output 'a' for the first char and 'd' for the second char.  I am getting an unrecognizable letter in the output for the first and second char, if anyone could point out where I went wrong with this header file. Thanks in advance.

Header File

```
template <class T>
class Pair
{
private:
    T firstChar;
    T secondChar;
public:
    Pair(const T& , const T&);
    T getFirst( );
    T getSecond( );
};

template <class T>
Pair<T>::Pair(const T&, const T&)
{
    firstChar;
    secondChar;
}

template <class T>
T Pair<T>::getFirst ( )
{
    return firstChar;
}

template <class T>
T Pair<T>::getSecond ( )
{
    return secondChar;
}
```

Driver File

```
#include <iostream>
#include "pair.h"
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    Pair<char> letters('a', 'd');
    cout << "\nThe first letter is: " << letters.getFirst();
    cout << "\nThe second letter is: " << letters.getSecond();
    cout << endl;
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor doesn't do anything useful. You want it to use its parameters to initialise the member variables:

```
template <class T>
Pair<T>::Pair(const T& first, const T& second) :
    firstChar(first),
    secondChar(second)
{}
```

If you enable compiler warnings, it should tell you that the statements `firstChar;` and `secondChar;` do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

```
template <class T>
Pair<T>::Pair(const T&, const T&)
{
    firstChar;
    secondChar;
}
```

This constructor doesn't do anything, it doesn't have any named argument nor it assigns them to the member attributes, maybe you wanted to use:

```
template <class T>
Pair<T>::Pair(const T& first, const T& second) : firstChar(first), secondChar(second)
{

}
```